# Unknown JSON (LinkedHashMap) to Java (POJO) class

Tags: java, json

I have a function that receives a JSON-object which is a LinkedHashMap. Now I need to parse that input to either one of three classes. This code works (using Jackson) but it doesn't feel right. Can this be done in a better way? Java Generics?

```
public String handleRequest(Object input)
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    ClassA classA = null;
    ClassB classB = null;
    ClassC classC = null;

    // Maybe A?
    try
    {
        classA = mapper.convertValue(input, ClassA.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    // Maybe B?
    try
    {
        classB = mapper.convertValue(input, ClassB.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    // Maybe C?
    try
    {
        classC = mapper.convertValue(input, ClassC.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    String status = "";

    if (classA != null)
        status = "Class A";

    if (classB != null)
        status = "Class B";

    if (classC != null)
        status = "Class C";

    return status;
}
```

Update:
`ClassA`, `ClassB`, and `classC` are all in the same package and looks similar to this with some small changes to not be identical:

```
public class ClassA
{
    String a;
    String b;
    String c;

    // ... getters and setters
}
```

Comment: could you provide more details on ClassA B and C?  Are they part of the same inheritence tree of completely unrelated classes?

Comment: sure, one second! Yes they are in the same package

Comment: Using jackson is the standard way to convert objects to json. Why do you have to think about other way ? Ofcourse there is a scope of better writing of your code. You can as well checkout gson https://github.com/google/gson @BakedInhalf

Comment: @AarishRamesh Jackson is fine, it's how I make three try-catch blocks, and I have to specify each class manually..